# "ColumnName" is not a recognized table hints option. error while Joining a table value function with a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a sample table like the one below

**table1**

```
chktid   ToUser
1        3
2        6
3        3
4        1
```

`chkid` is the parentId and sometimes this parent has childs and each of them, has sub-childs and so on

I have written a function to return all the childs and sub-childs of the particular `chktid`. Calling my function `dbo.hierychyreturnfn(chktid)` with different `chktid` as input parameter, I am getting the following results

For **chktid = 1** and so `select * from dbo.hierychyreturnfn(1)`, the output is:

```
chkchildid
10
11
12
13
```

For **chktid = 2** and so `select * from dbo.hierychyreturnfn(2)`, the output is:

```
chkchildid
14
15
16
```

For **chktid = 3** and so `select * from dbo.hierychyreturnfn(3)`, the output is:

```
chkchildid
19
```

For **chktid = 4** and so `select * from dbo.hierychyreturnfn(4)`, it returns no rows since chkid=4 has no childs.

My question is: Is there any way to join the function and table 1 and return all results?
My expected out put is:

```
chkid       ToUser      chkchildid
1               3           10
1               3           11
1               3           12
1               3           13
2               6           14
2               6           15
2               6           16
3               3           19
```

I am trying to use cross apply for getting this

```
SELECT a.chkid
    ,a.ToUser
    ,b.chkchildid
FROM table1 a
CROSS APPLY dbo.hierychyreturnfn(1) b // need to join table1 and pass each chkid
```

But I don't know how to pass each `chkid` to `hierychyreturnfn()`. I am stuck here. I have also tried code  below also but it gives an error

> "chkid" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a
>   parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function,
>   ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

```
SELECT a.chkid
    ,a.ToUser
    ,b.chkchildid
FROM table1 a
CROSS APPLY dbo.hierychyreturnfn(chkid) b
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: And have you done what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes i have searched a lot, most of the links says need to alter database, but it is not possible in my case.

Comment: Yes you need to set the compatibility of the database just like the error message states. Is there a reason you have to run in 2000 compatibility mode?

Comment: @SeanLange the db is in customer side so db alteration is difficult, is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: The problem is that because of the compatibility level it can't handle the table valued function. You either need to change the compatibility level or write your sql without the table valued function.

Comment: should be closed, @SeanLange s comment is the answer in my opinion